# Super user implementation in DDD

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to figure out how to apply security to my ddd scenario.

As an example let's take a `moderatePost` method from Vernon's book.
The rule is that only Moderator of Forum can moderate a post in this Forum:

```
    public void moderatePost(
            Post aPost,
            Moderator aModerator,
            String aSubject,
            String aBodyText) {

        this.assertStateFalse(this.isClosed(), "Forum is closed.");
        this.assertArgumentNotNull(aPost, "Post may not be null.");
        this.assertArgumentEquals(aPost.forumId(), this.forumId(), "Not a post of this forum.");
        this.assertArgumentTrue(this.isModeratedBy(aModerator), "Not the moderator of this forum.");

        aPost.alterPostContent(aSubject, aBodyText);
    }
```

[source code](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/9b27b11773f62afb5d1b541abf51fb36516a7250/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/domain/model/forum/Forum.java#L121)

In some applications there is admin (super user) that has privileges to do every action in the system. How can I add "super user" to such modeled domain? The only solution I can imagine is to add overloaded `moderatePost` method that bypass the `isModeratedBy` assertion, but in such scenario it is easy to imagine that someone will use such method in application layer instead of existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't alter or overload the moderatePost.

Just give your super user the moderator right from the IAM Context, and every rights. Sounds cumbersome but it wont make you change your prod code, makes audit more simple (you can trace which user have which role) with no magic super user.

Let's say the IAM send a new event UserAssignedToRole (SuperUser), in your collaboration context you would listen to this event like its done in https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_agilepm/src/main/java/com/saasovation/agilepm/port/adapter/messaging/rabbitmq/RabbitMQTeamMemberEnablerListener.java

Another option is to add SuperUser as part of the domain, just like its done for Moderator and Author, and the assertion would become something like this:

> this.assertArgumentTrue(this.isModeratedBy(aModerator) || this.isSuperUser(aModerator), "Not the moderator of this forum.");